# If I write out a solo endorsement and I decide I want to change the limitations

Tags: safety, student-pilot, cfi, logbook-endorsements, solo-flight

I am a new CFI and I just gave out my first solo endorsement.
If I write out a student solo endorsement and decide I want to change the limitations. Can I? And if so, do I need to write out a new one or can I cross it out and initial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, which asks about changing an endorsement that you've already written.  However, for future students, you could consider not writing any specific limitations in the endorsement at all, and instead referencing an external document:

> I certify that [First name, MI, Last name] has received the required training to qualify for solo flying. I have determined [he or she] meets the applicable requirements of § 61.87(n) and is proficient to make solo flights in [make and model], **subject to the limitations specified on [his or her] current Orville's Flyin School Student Pilot Card.**

We did this at the flight school I worked at.  Since the Pilot Card (or whatever document you want) isn't part of the student's logbook, you as the CFI can change it at any time, as many times as you need.

(Our FSDO inspector particularly liked that we were able to modify a student's limitations especially with the onset of winter weather.)

Comment: I like that thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous question, my answer assumes that you are asking about operations in the U.S. under the Federal Aviation Regulations.

You certainly can change the student pilot solo endorsement limitation(s) at any time you find it necessary. It is quite reasonable, for example, that as your student gains experience and skill that you may want to revise a solo endorsement's limitation(s) regarding wind or crosswind velocities, etc. There may be other circumstances that come to your attention and cause you to decide to change/revise the limitations prior to the expiration of the 90 day endorsement time period.

Further, I believe that as long as the student pilot adheres to the limitations contained in the FAR 61.89(a)(8) endorsement the CFI would have (some/most/all) liability if an incident directly related to the scope of that limitation occurred.  So, if the CFI determines that a limitation needs to be revised it would be prudent for him/her to do so.

The [FAR 61.87 (p)(4)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.87(p)) 90 day student pilot solo endorsement and the FAR [FAR 61.89 (a)(8)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.89(a)(8)) student pilot general limitations provision read together with the [McHenry FAA Interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/faa_migrate/interps/2015/McHenry_2015_Legal_Interpretation.pdf) indicate that the 90 day student solo endorsement can be superseded with revised limitations. Below is a pertinent excerpt from that Interpretation.  However, a complete reading of the entire document will also be helpful with respect to the point you are asking about in your question:

[image]

If I were to change a solo endorsement by adding or changing any limitation(s), I would cross out the old endorsement leaving it readable and place the word "superseded" or "void" (or similar) next to it and then write a new one with the revised limitation(s). This would make clear what your intentions with respect to the endorsement are and show a historical (and readable) sequence of the circumstances/limitations under which you are authorizing your student to conduct solo flight.

Comment: Thank you so much. That answers my question

Comment: @Someone I believe that the CFI can revoke/supersede a 90 day student solo endorsement.

Comment: @RTO Superseding requires replacing it with another endorsement of the same type. Where are you getting the idea that revoking it is an option?

Comment: @Chris  Well, the language of the interpretation says the endorsement remains valid until it **expires** or is **superseded**. This to me, makes clear that "expires" means after 90 days and "superseded" means *to displace in favor of another." Both words have a different meaning.  "Another endorsement of the same type" means, to me, another 90 solo endorsement as opposed to a cross country solo endorsement. I can't find anything in the regs that would prevent a CFI from superseding a 90 day solo endorsement with another 90 day endorsement for any reason at a time the CFI thought was necessary.

Comment: @Chris I can remember a time many years ago that after giving a 90 solo endorsement to a student the weather, after about 45 days, started to be quite unpredictable as winter approached.  I decided that relying on the regulatory requirement that there be 3 miles vis during the day (for solo) was not adequate considering the potential for rapidly changing weather. So I wrote a  revised (superseded) endorsement requiring that my student could not solo unless the reported vis was at least 5 miles day and 10 miles night. No reg preventing this and it was a prudent action on my part as the CFI.

Comment: @RTO There's nothing in the regs that says an instructor *can* revoke or modify any endorsement, either. It seems pretty clear that, say, a tailwheel endorsement can't be revoked, so what is the regulatory basis for being able to revoke a solo endorsement?

Comment: Limiting the weather a student pilot can fly in is of course prudent. And §61.89(a)(8) allows you to write limitations that aren't necessarily connected to an endorsement, I suppose.

Comment: @Chris I think the tailwheel endorsement and the 90 day student solo endorsement are apple and oranges in comparison.  I have a continuing responsibility for the student whereas the tailwheel is a one and done endorsement. Also, I think the McHenry interpretation supports my opinion.  In any event,  I agree to disagree. I'm all for providing close and careful oversight of student pilots. Thanks for your point of view.